# Firebase with F# and Visual Studio

Tags: ios, firebase, f#

Is there any way to use Firebase with F# iOS Development in Visual Studio? I have created an iOS app using xCode and Swift which is heavily dependent on a FIrebase backend and need to now translate it into F#, however I am unable to find any information regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can use a third party lib to do the job. Some I've tested before are:

https://github.com/fsharp-playground/fsharp-firebase

https://github.com/ruxo/FsFirebase

There is also a package in nugget called [FsFireBase](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsFirebase/)

Comment: did these allow you to use things like `FirebaseAuth` or just the basic POST, GET etc?

Comment: As long as i know it only support basic operations like GET PUT PATCH POST DELETE. There are [others nugget packages](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/FirebaseAuthentication.net) that works with Firebase Authentication but i don't know right now if has support for F#

Comment: so I figured out that you can do authentication using the REST api and sending POST requests, thanks!